# Download zip archive from blobstore in Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I worked on Google app engine with python. I created zip archives into tho blobstore, but there is a problem when I try to download this file.

I will show some details: first, I created this archive on the blob and then I got the key of this uploaded file. I want to send this key in url to another python page like this:

```
print'<a href="download.py?key=%s">Save Zip</a>' % blob_key
```

Now in download.py page, I tried to get the key from the url as:
self.request.get('key'), but it doesn't work.

In this page I wrote

```
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
```

......etc

This is the only class I used to download the zip, but the problem is I can't get the key, and when I run the application, I get this problem:

```
****Status: 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0****
```

app.yaml code:

```
application: cloudcomputingproject20122012
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /compress.py
  script: compress.py
- url: /decompress.py
  script: decompress.py
- url: (.*)/
  static_files: static\1/index.html
  upload: static/index.html
```

Now in compress.py i made two classes;creating zip,storing it on blobstore,getting the bob key for this stored file then i defined blob key as global variable ,now in serve handler class i try to download this zip,but i can't.

```
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self):

    global x 
    #x="tvsD0KgYxX85hyC9wJHsqw=="
    print x
    x = str(urllib.unquote(x))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(x)
    self.send_blob(blob_info,save_as=True)



def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication( [('/serve', ServeHandler),], debug=True)
    c=zip()
    c.z()
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You really, really don't want to generate your HTML output with `print` statement. Just don't do it. Invest a little bit of time in learning a Python templating engine. The Django 1.2 engine is included with the AppEngine SDK.

Comment: Jinja is also included with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Python on App Engine is not like PHP - request URLs do not map directly to filenames; you can't point to `/download.php` and expect requests to be routed to your handler. You need to map your handler to a URL, then point requests at that URL; see any of the Getting Started tutorials for examples.

Comment: ,i understood from your comment that i can't pass any parameter (as key in my code)from python page to another?but what can i do for this problem because in the first page i created the zip on the blobstore and send the key of this zip into other python page.

Comment: @Eng_Engineer You can pass query string parameters just fine - again, check out any of the getting started guides for examples. Before you can do any of this, you have to understand the basics of writing an app in App Engine; that includes mapping URLs to handlers.

Comment: :i wrote zip archives into blobstore in app engine ,and it's worked correctly,as in this guide http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore
but the problem exactly when i download or get this blob (zip)from the storage.

Comment: @Eng_Engineer As I said, the issue you're having isn't specific to this task - you simply need to learn how to map URLs to handlers. In fact, if you've already written other handlers that work, you should be able to see this - you need to add the handler to your application definition, not try and reference the Python module directly in the URL.

Comment: @Eng_Engineer You need a handler definition in app.yaml, which points to a module that contains a WSGI application. Again, this is not specific to your question, and it's covered by every getting started guide. Start with one of them.

Comment: :Thanks for your help, i tried a new approach that i put the creation of the zip and storing this zip in one class,and serving(downloading)this store zip in another class:
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
When i called these classes in main i called creation and storing the zip  class but the serverhandler i ran it using ::run_wsgi_app(application) but there was an error :Status: 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0,please i want a solution as soon as possible.Thanks

Comment: You're not listening. You need to map the URL you want to use to this handler. You do that by making sure it's mapped in app.yaml and in your application definition, just like you have for every other handler. Please, go back and read the getting started guide.

Comment: @ Nick Johnson you don't understand to me exactly the handlers in app.yaml page is exist correctly,i raed getting started guide,please my problem that the servehandler can't executed, i don't know the problemm i used only this google app engine handler.Thanks

Comment: @Eng_Engineer Then you need to include the actual code from your handler, and your application definition, and your app.yaml in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the example [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob)? It seems you're doing exactly the same thing.

```
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
  def get(self, resource):
    resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource)
    self.send_blob(blob_info)
```

Comment: Sir.Stuart,yes i used this class in download.py page but the problem exactly i can't get the key from the previous page which i created zip archive in that page.

Comment: Sir.Adam i'm using eclipse for java developer and it's support the HTML,but the action in a href is exucted correctly,like this:
http://localhost:8080/download.py?key=xuMgQfOSPo1n2YOYhm1Eow==,but the problem i can't get this key from the url,Thanks for your help,have you any idea please?

Comment: How did you create the zip? Once again the example is pretty clear on how to redirect to the downloadhandler to send the blob.

Comment: As this:
zip_file = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/zip'),and it's created successful on the storage but the problem i create the zip in page and send the key for this zip to (download.py_page,and i can't get this key at the download.py.Thanks

Comment: zip_file = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/zip',_blobinfo_uploaded_filename=text_content+'.zip')
with files.open(zip_file, 'a') as f:
    
    f.write(zipstream.getvalue())
files.finalize(zip_file)
blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(zip_file)
#print blob_key
blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
print'<a href="download.py?key=%s">Download Zip</a>' % blob_key